# Localizar e substituir antes e depois usando um coringa sql

Tags: sql

Tenho uma lista de mais de 5000 cartas com nomes diferentes e um `-` (hífen) em comum. Exemplo:

```
Evilswarm Exciton Knight LVAL-EN056   
Number 101: Silent Honor ARK LVAL-E47  
Number 11: Big Eye GAV-EN090  
Lavalval Chain HA07-EN019
```

O que gostaria de como fazer é substituir ou excluir a partir do hífen X caracteres após e antes, para o resultado ficar assim:

```
Lavalval Chain -
```

Estava usando

```
UPDATE cartas SET nome=LEFT(nome, LEN(nome)-5)
```

porém os tamanhos são diferentes.

Não preciso executar as duas funções ao mesmo tempo, caso tiverem alguma ideia de somente excluir 1 caractere antes do `-` já me dará uma base de como fazer.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar expressões regulares? No PostgreSQL você tem a função regexp_replace e encontra as explicações em: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: acabei usando as expressoes no excel removi e upei o banco denovo, mais era esse caminho mesmo, quanto a postgresql nunca mexi com ele, de todo jeito valeu

Comment: @ArsomNolasco vi que você resolveu com regex, mas de qualquer forma atualizei a resposta de acordo com o enunciado, usando SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Esta é uma tarefa bem simples para resolver usando funções tradicionais. Seguem dois exemplos para dois dialetos comuns de *SQL*, mas com certeza você consegue adaptar para praticamente qualquer versão e linguagem.

O segredo está na função que localiza uma string dentro da outra, e retorna a posição numericamente:

Primeiro, rodamos este select para obter a string até o `-`:

```
UPDATE cartas SET nome = IIF(
   CHARINDEX( nome, '-' ) = 0,
   nome,
   LEFT( nome, CHARINDEX( nome, '-' ) )
);
```

Agora, `Number 11: Big Eye GAV-EN090` ficou apenas `Number 11: Big Eye GAV-`.

Em seguida, usamos a segunda query para pegar apenas até o espaço anterior ao `GAV-`:

```
UPDATE cartas SET nome = IIF(
   CHARINDEX( REVERSE(nome), ' ' ) = 0,
   "",
   REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE(nome), CHARINDEX( REVERSE(nome), ' ' ) + 1 ) )
);
```

Tinhamos conseguido `Number 11: Big Eye GAV-` e agora temos `Number 11: Big Eye`!

> Em T-SQL use `CHARINDEX()`, `IIF()` e `SUBSTRING()`, no MySQL use `INSTR()`, `IF()` e `SUBSTR()`

### Funções usadas:

- `IIF(condicao,seVerdadeiro,seFalso)` dependendo da condição retorna um dos dois valores;
- `CHARINDEX(palheiro, agulha)` retorna a posição numérica da `agulha` dentro do `palheiro`;
- `LEFT(string, quantidade)` retorna a `quantidade` de caracteres iniciais da `string`;
- `REVERSE(string)` inverte a string, transformando `abc` em `bca`.
- `SUBSTRING(string,inicio,quantidade)` retorna a quantidade de caracteres da string à partir da posição início.

Answer (score 0):

acabei usando as expressões regulares do excel onde  busquei com ...-... e substitui por -, funcionou bem , depois importei denovo pro banco, depois irei pesquisar se o sql tem isso e como usar de todo jeito valeu ai aos comentearios e respostas.

Para quem quiser saber sobre expressão regulares no Broffice segue o link

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions/pt-BR

Comment: poderia elaborar um pouco melhor sua resposta, para que assim outras pessoas que enfrentem o mesmo problema que voce futuramente consigam usar sua solução?

Comment: 2 dias para votar a favor, quanto a elaboração da resposta acho que fui bastante direto, revisei, e para quem conhece expressão regulares basta ir no famoso crtl + f = find(localizar) e procurar usando as expressões de todo jeito nao custa passar o  link

Comment: Perdoe a minha ignorância, mas o que o BROffice tem a ver com SQL?

Comment: ele exporta e importa tabelas sql